# How can we know the Topology of $\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R ^2 : f(x,y)=0 \}$

Tags: algebraic-curves, low-dimensional-topology, real-algebraic-geometry

Let $f \in \Bbb R[x,y]$ be a given polynomial and set
$$V=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2 : f(x,y)=0\}$$

1. How can we tell if $V\neq \emptyset$ ?
2. How can we know if $V$ is compact?
3. How can we tell if $V$ is connected (or how many connected components it has)?

Of course, i don't take "ploting the set" as an answer. I want some kind of algorithm to answer this questions in terms of the given polynomial. Take in consideration that I'm working with real numbers, not complex.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/662036/is-there-a-general-way-to-solve-a-multivariate-polynomial, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4094417/using-gröbner-bases-and-cylindrical-algebraic-decomposition-to-solve-real-polyno?rq=1, and others.

Comment: Very hard question. If you can bring it into the explicit form $y=g(x)$ where $g(x)$ is a rational function then it is homeomorphic to a finite set whose cardinality is one more then the number of poles of g(x) without multiplicities.

Comment: This kind of question is part of "real algebraic geometry", whose name is a little misleading, since it's not just alg geom over the real number field, but allows inequalities and such, specific to the real numbers. Eminently google-able.

Comment: All these are decidable (Tarsky's work) but algorithms will be slow.

Comment: You may find [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journalArticle/Download?urlId=10.1216%2FRMJ-1988-18-3-655) interesting. In particular, it says that if f is a cubic then there are at most 4 connected components. Though this is approached mostly through classifying plane cubics and not through more general analysis of the topology of such curves.

Comment: Wow, I thought this was a long-ago solved problem but apparently is not that simple

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Gröbner bases and Cylindrical Algebraic Decomposition to solve real polynomial systems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4094417/using-gr%c3%b6bner-bases-and-cylindrical-algebraic-decomposition-to-solve-real-polyno)

Comment: I don't want to solve a system, I want to understand its topology